Analytical Equivalent Crystal Theory
I need some help in the calculation of the surface energy of a high  index plane crystal using the Analytical Equivalent Crystal Theory (AECT) Method.
I am new to the find so, it would be appreciated if details of the calculation can be shown.
Thanks

Hi Emmanuel Enukpere. Welcome to Phys.SE. Consider to include some references for clarity.
